# Как забрать данные из текстовых полей при клике на кнопку?

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Как забрать данные из текстовых полей при клике на кнопку?

Comment: А кто прошёлся и по минусовал?

Comment: Не имею привычки.

Comment: Мой пример 100% ты минусанул(((

Comment: @danpetruk есть ощущение, что кто-то основательно этим занялся - из последних вопросов почти все заминусованы, притом без какой-то выдающейся глупости со стороны спрашивавщих

Comment: Может @asen зарегал ещё один акк, набрал репы и принялся за дело?

Comment: @danpetruk это какой-то легендарный любитель с..ть в тапки?

Comment: @DreamChild у него и другие шалости были, вот последняя история http://hashcode.ru/questions/128531/%D1%85%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-asen

Comment: любопытно. Я, правда, не застал всех этих замечательных событий, но, судя по всему, личность была забавная. Одна только формулировка в его адрес "ХэшКод pwned Asen" чего стоит)

Comment: @DreamChild я тоже не застал, но я люблю читать старые вопросы дискуссии. Так и узнал о нём. 

p.s. если зайдёте в его профиль, то найдёте кое-что объясняющие его поведение. Правда в моём профиле есть тоже это, только ещё хуже, но тем ни менее в него я всё равно не клонируюсь

Comment: `a =document.getElementById('text_id').value;` если на js, `a = $("text_id").val();` если на jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("button").click(function(){
var a = $("input").val();
});
```

Вот супер простой пример на jQuery

Comment: Если в метках не написано jquery, то зачем на нём писать ответ? Или вам метка nojquery нужна? :)

Comment: ИМХО Лучше такой пример на JQuery, чем Ваш на JS

Answer (score 2):

Обернуть все input'ы в форму и использовать (пример на jQuery)

```
$('form').serialize(); // или serializeArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" value="1">
<input type="text" id="txt2" value="2">
<input type="text" id="txt3" value="3">
<input type="text" id="txt4" value="4">
<input type="text" id="txt5" value="5">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="button" onclick="getInputVal()">
```

html5 javascript:

```
function getInputVal() {
    var a = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');
    for (var b = 0, c = a.length; b < c; b++){
         console.log(a[b].value);//получаем все значения полей
    }
}
```

html4 javascript:

```
function getInputVal() {
   var a = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
   for (var b = 0, c = a.length; b < c; b++){
      if (a[b].type == 'text') {
         //if (/txt\d+/i.test(a[b].id)) //при необходимости проверка на id == txtчисло
         console.log(a[b].value);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<input id="txt">
<button onclick="gav()">
```

---

```
function gav() {
var data = document.getElementById('txt'); //вот эти данные

}
```

Comment: Так лучше не делать Вы смешиваете логику и представление

Comment: "*Котлекты отдельно, мухи отдельно*". Зачем js в html встраивать?

    <input type="text" id="txt" value="Some Value">
    <input type="button" id="btn">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    btn.onclick = function(){
        console.log(txt.value);
    };
    </script>

Comment: @Deonis чтобы показать где html, а где скрипт. Неужели АО не догадается разъединить?